# Merge Sort Implementation Check

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, mergesort

I am doubtful of my implementation of the merge sort for two cases specifically:


1. If the size of the list is 2, then I have swapped the values if they are not in the ascending order else I have returned them.


2. In the merge function when the list tries to check outside the number of elements in it, I have assigned the greatest number (`9999`), so that in case of comparison with it always comes false.

Can anyone tell me if the implementation of my merge sort is correct or not? As in sorting is complete, but is the implementation of merge sort exact or is it wrong because of the cases?


Here is my code:

```
# unsorted LIST
u_list = [3, 6, 8, 1, 4, 7, 2, 12, 45];

# Size of the unsorted list
global_size = len(u_list)

def foo(temp_list):
    size_of_list = len(temp_list)
    # If the size of the list is 1
    if size_of_list == 1:
        return temp_list

    # If the size of the list is 2
    if size_of_list == 2:
        if temp_list[0] > temp_list[1]:
            temp_list[0],temp_list[1] = temp_list[1],temp_list[0]
            return temp_list
        else: 
            return temp_list

    # If the size of the list is greater than 2                
    if size_of_list > 2:
        count = 1
        i = 0
        if size_of_list % 2 == 0:
            mid1 = size_of_list / 2
        else:
            mid1 = (size_of_list / 2) + 1

        mid2 = size_of_list - mid1

        newlist1 = list()
        newlist2 = list()

        for e in temp_list:
            if count >= mid1 + 1:
                newlist2.append(e)
            else:
                newlist1.append(e)
            if count == size_of_list:
                break
            count = count + 1
        sorted_list = list()
        return merge(foo(newlist1), foo(newlist2))

# Merging all the sorted components
def merge(list1, list2):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    size_of_list = len(list1) + len(list2)
    sorted_list = list()
    while k <= size_of_list - 1:
        if i == len(list1):
            list1.append(9999)
        if j == len(list2):
            list2.append(9999)

        if list1[i] < list2[j]:
            sorted_list.append(list1[i])
            i = i + 1
        elif list2[j] < list1[i]:
            sorted_list.append(list2[j])
            j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
    return sorted_list

print foo(u_list)
```

Comment: This looks like it might be homework.  Is that the case?

Comment: Its not homework.. I have joined my job and i am actually brushing up my programming skills...So i was implementing merge sort for practise.. And the code is able to sort perfectly any unsorted list but i just wanted know if it follows the algorithm exactly..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To be honest, I feel very uneasy if I see code like this ;). It may be correct, but my guts feeling sais it's not (what if there are numbers > 9999?). It is more complicated than necessary. The syntax is Python, but you are not using the power of Python.

Here's how I would implement merge sort in Python:

```
def merge_sort(sequence):
    if len(sequence) < 2: 
        return sequence

    mid = int(len(sequence) / 2)
    left_sequence = merge_sort(sequence[:mid])
    right_sequence = merge_sort(sequence[mid:])
    return merge(left_sequence, right_sequence)

def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    i = j = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1 
    result += left[i:]
    result += right[j:]

    return result
```

Comment: I had learned python just a week before...so never knew how to use it in a minimalistic sense.... Plus from your code I now know what was i doing wrong in my code... I was comparing 9999 with the other list to get false so that the compiler moves on to the next list comparison ... but now i realize as both lists are sorted i can directly append them to the result.. Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

## Not the most cleanest of codes but it will get the job done by merge sort method.

Method 1:

```
def merge_sorted(list1,list2):

    sorted = []

    i = 0

    k = 0

    while True:
        if i >= len(list1):                                                     
            sorted.extend(list2[k:])
            return sorted

        if k >= len(list2):
            sorted.extend(list1[i:])                                   
            return sorted

        if list1[i] <= list2[k]:
            sorted.append(list1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            sorted.append(list2[k])
            k += 1
```

Method 2:

```
def sort_method2(list0):

    unsorted_list = list0[:]

    if (len(unsorted_list) == 1 or len(unsorted_list) == 0): 

        return(unsorted_list)

    elif(len(unsorted_list) == 2): 

        if (unsorted_list[0] > unsorted_list[1]):

            temp = unsorted_list[0]

            unsorted_list[0] = unsorted_list[1]

            unsorted_list[1] = temp

        return(unsorted_list)
    else:
        length = len(unsorted_list)//2   

        first_list = sort_method2(unsorted_list[length:])   

        second_list = sort_method2(unsorted_list[:length]) 

        return(merge_sorted(first_list,second_list))
```

list3 = [8,8,2,63,2,6,3,4,2,6,2,6,8,5,4,3,6,-1,21,0,1,23,623,4,0.001,5,4,256,4,0]

sort_method2(list3)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive version:
it's memory efficient to remove the value from the sorted_lists once that is pushed into the merged_list, which is done using pop().

```
"""
This function merges two sorted arrays using recursion( sorted from left to right)
e.g
a = [1,2,3,4] and b = [5,6,7,8]
lets represent them like they are stacks and the smallest values can be popped out
so we send reversed lists into the function

_merge_two_sorted_lists(a[::-1], b[::-1])

"""
def _merge_two_sorted_lists(a1_L, b1_L, merged_sorted_lists = None):
    if merged_sorted_lists is None:
        merged_sorted_lists = []
    if not a1_L and not b1_L:
        return merged_sorted_lists

    if a1_L and b1_L:
        if a1_L[-1] < b1_L[-1]:
            merged_sorted_lists.append(a1_L.pop())
        else:
            merged_sorted_lists.append(b1_L.pop())
    elif a1_L and not b1_L:
        merged_sorted_lists.append(a1_L.pop())
    elif not a1_L and b1_L:
        merged_sorted_lists.append(b1_L.pop())

    return _merge_two_sorted_lists(a1_L, b1_L, merged_sorted_lists)
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [3,4]
>>> _merge_two_sorted_lists(a[::-1],b[::-1])
>>> [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```