# Python - Merge Sort Recursive Algorithm

Tags: python, function, recursion, pseudocode

I was trying to implement this pseudocode for the recursive merge sort algorithm:

```
**procedure**  *mergesort*(L = a1, a2,…,an )
**if**  n  > 1 **then** 
     m := ⌊n/2⌋
     L1 := a1, a2,…,am 
     L2 := am+1, am+2,…,an
     L   := merge(mergesort(L1), mergesort(L2 ))
{L is now sorted into elements in increasing order}

**procedure**  *merge*(L1, L2 :sorted lists)
L := empty list
**while** L1  and L2  are both nonempty
 remove smaller of first elements of L1 and L2 from its list; 
         put at the right end of L
 **if** this removal makes one list empty 
     **then** remove all elements from the other list and append them to L
return L {L is the merged list with the elements in increasing order}
```

The purpose its to write it on python, so far I have coded all of it but it does not run properly, everytime I run it prints: function merge at 0x0000000002024730. Here is the python code:

```
#Recursive Merge Sort
import math
ent = [10000, 967, 87, 91, 117, 819, 403, 597, 1201, 12090]
def merge(L1, L2):

        while len(L1) and len(L2) != 0:
            L.append(L1[0])
            L1.remove(L1[0])
            L.append(L2[0])
            L2.remove(L2[0])
            if len(L1) == 0:
                L.append(L2)
            elif len(L2) == 0:
                L.append(L1)
        return L


def mergesort(ent):

if len(ent)>1:
    m=math.floor(len(ent)/2)
    L1 = []
    L2 = []
    L1=L1+ent[:m]
    L2=L2+ent[m+1:len(ent)]
    L=merge(mergesort(L1),mergesort(L2))




print(merge)
```

I have some doubts about how the functions are supossed to work recursively together, which is why I think I cant solve and code it right. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: @alienhard gave a very good version in this [question][1].

 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112789/merge-sort-implementation-check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not executing `merge`, but printing the function *itself*. Do this:

```
print(merge())
```

However, your logic is a bit messed up, you don't even have a recursive function there.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761766/mergesort-python)

Also, i think what you need is to call mergesort:

```
def mergesort(ent):
    if len(ent)>1:
        m=math.floor(len(ent)/2)
        L1 = ent[:m]
        L2 = ent[m+1:len(ent)]
        L=merge(mergesort(L1),mergesort(L2))
return L
```

And execute it:

```
print(mergesort(ent))
```

Comment: I was just following the giving pseudocode, my first time coding python :), but I tried what you suggested and it returns:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*\Documents\A7\15.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(merge(L1,L2))
NameError: name 'L1' is not defined

Comment: You need to pass a value to `merge`, since it's expecting it. Perhaps you meant to execute `mergesort`?

Comment: I passed the value in the last line of mergesort, dont know if correctly but I think so, also printed mergesort(ent) and the compiler started whining about it, the merge(mergesort(L1),mergesort(L2)) statement, I want them to be mergesorted to then go to the merge function, recursively

Comment: To see what your function should look like, click the link i provided. This is too difficult for you to do right now. Don't give up, learn some more!

Comment: File "C:\Users\*\Documents\A7\15.py", line 6, in merge
    while len(L1) and len(L2) != 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Its what it returns after executing it exactly as you sugested in the answer above, Ill try haha its just that its for an assignment for tommorow

Comment: I've got a bunch of sorts in Python at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/sorts/compare/trunk - including a merge sort.  Actually, they're m4 that can generate pure python or cython.

Comment: Really thanks guys but I can't copy things :(, I continued playing around with my code and changed the las part of mergesort function to L1=mergesort(L1) and 2 but now when executing merge(L1, L2) it outputs that: NameError: name 'L1' is not defined, when its everywhere, I dont understand this error