# How to do this sort practice?

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, mergesort

```
def combine (l1,l2):
    if l1 == []:
        return l2
    if l2 == []:
        return l1
    if l1[0] <= l2[0]:
        return [l1[0]] + combine(l1[1:], l2)
    return [l2[0]] + combine(l1, l2[1:])
```

I'm trying to practice defining a function named "sort" to recursively merge the list and return a new list (not mutating the argument) that contains
every value from its argument list, but in sorted/non-descending order.

```
def sort(l):
    if l == []:
        return []
    else:
        l1, l2 = l[0:int(len(l)/2)], l[int(len(l)/2):]
        s = combine(l1, l2)
        return sort(s)
```

However, it always gives me an error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: This type of sort is called [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Merge Sort Recursive Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992992/python-merge-sort-recursive-algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

Your `sort` function is recursively calling itself with the same size input over and over again if `l` has any items. This will eventually result to `RuntimeError`. If you change your function to split the given `list` to two, sorting the halves and combining the result it works as expected:

```
def merge_sort(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l

    return combine(merge_sort(l[0:len(l)/2]), merge_sort(l[len(l)/2:]))
```

Since the above function splits the given `list` to two the recursion will eventually terminate when `len(l) <= 1`.